# After scrolling table cell image display previous images in swift. Though the image url display correct

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem in cell image. I am describe it in bellow.
A screen having a table containing 1000 cells.
Each cell consist of a) image b) labels.
The image and the labels data are comes from json.
 
By using of AFNetwork I purse json and bind label and image. The problem is in image. The labels are perfectly bind. From json the image url also come correctly. But display previous cell images when scrolling is started. 
1st time when scrolling not start all image are display perfectly. But after scrolling problem start and show previous cell image.

**Code:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if self.arrPostImage![indexPath.row] as! String == ""
    {
        let cell1: CellNewNoImage = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2") as! CellNewNoImage
        return cell1
     }
     else
     {
         let cell1: CellForMyActivityMainTableView = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CellForMyActivityMainTableView
        cell1.title.text = self.arrTitle![indexPath.row] as? String
        cell1.postDate.text = self.arrPostDate![indexPath.row] as? String
        cell1.postDescription.text = self.arrPostDescription![indexPath.row] as? String

        //=========== Problem  Start  ====================        
        self.arrPostPersonImg![indexPath.row] =  self.arrPostPersonImg![indexPath.row].stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
        let imgPath = self.arrPostPersonImg![indexPath.row]
        let url12 = NSURL(string:imgPath as! String )
        getDataFromUrl(url12!) { (data, response, error)  in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }
            cell1.postPersonImg.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
    self.arrPostImage![indexPath.row] =  self.arrPostImage![indexPath.row].stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
    let imgPath2 = self.arrPostImage![indexPath.row]
    let url122 = NSURL(string:imgPath2 as! String )
    if let url = NSURL(string:imgPath2 as! String) {
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
        cell1.postImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }        
}
return cell1
}
```

}

```
func getDataFromUrl(url:NSURL, completion: ((data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError? ) -> Void))
{
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url)
    { (data, response, error) in
        completion(data: data, response: response, error: error)
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381991/ios-cache-policy

Answer (score 1):

When you are setting your postPersonImage with URL
 set that image view image nil before your image path and try. like

```
cell1.postPersonImg.image = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the previous image from the cell before loading the new one.

I actually made a Pod to manage cache for images, so you will not download the same image several times : https://cocoapods.org/?q=cmimageloader