# jQuery send AJAX return 404 in Safari

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-status-code-404, mobile-safari

The code I used always fine in computer browser,
but when I use Safari in smart phone,
it will return 404 while I first connect the page.
If I refresh the page in Safari( of the smart phone),
then everything is okay( it doesn't return 404 anymore, until I clear the cache of the Safari browser).

So I'm sure the web page( the url) is correct.

Any one know what's wrong?

I use jquery-2.0.3( not sure it's the version cause the problem),
and the code is simple as any example everywhere:

```
$.post('url', {
    data
}).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(jqXHR.status);
}).success(function(data) {

});
```

even use $.ajax will cause same problem:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    type: "get",
    dataType: "text xml",
    data: data
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(jqXHR.status);
    },
    success: function(data){

    }
});
```

I say it again, everything is okay in computer browser,
so the path of url is correct.
And I type the url directly in Safari, Safari can find it,
so the problem isn't the wrong url.

I've heard there are some problems in Safari when use jQuery AJAX
( send http request),
And my file is in the same domain( in the web directory of the server).

Or is any situation will cause the pages always don't get data when you first enter it?

Thanks for suggestion in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

You can also handle various status codes using ajax.Try this

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: someURL,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: "json",
        statusCode: {
            404: function() {
                // handle the 404 response
            },
            401: function() {
                // handle the 401 response
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I think the problem isn't the 404( though it show up, but after I refresh the page, the 404 never show up).
And the same code will never show 404 in computer browser, only show up in Safari while first time enter the page.

Answer (score 0):

It's the problem as the link:
[cachePolicy in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381991/ios-cache-policy)

The url I run is under https (ssl authentication),

and Safari will set NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy = 0 in default.

Thus the page will be blocked in the beginning based on the default setting.

It's the problem of Safari,

but I'm not iOS coder, that's the reason why I don't know why and how to find the problem.

Hope it's helpful to other web designer.